# Maintenance Plan for ASP.Net SQL Server SessionState (ASPState) Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session-state, maintenance-plan

I'd like to clarify what the optimal maintenance plan set up is for the ASPState database that is used by ASP.Net SQL Server session state.

The standard user database maintenance plan doesn't seem suitable. I'll never need to do a point-in-time restore of session data so it seems pointless to back up the database and transaction log files. However I still need to truncate the transaction log, run integrity checks and update statistics.

There must be existing guidance out there somewhere but my google-fu is failing me right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the database recovery model is 'Simple'
Create a maintenance plan with these options:
- Check database integrity
- Reorganize index
- Clean up history

Schedule this once a week and you should be fine.